# Android: How to set status bar and navigation bar semi transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

In some applications I noticed that the status bar and navigational bar are transparent however, not completely. I do not know if this is a background color or something else. Would someone tell me how to implement this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this two method:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#20111111"));
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor("#20111111"));
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know the exact color Google uses?

Comment: i dont know exact color but Color.parseColor("#20111111") this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close.

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'm getting  opaque color

Answer (score 6):

There is a bit more to it than just setting the navigation bar color and the statusbar color, you have to actually have your content appear underneath both.

I use the following method in my utils class to set it in the activity before `setContentView`

```
public static void setWindowStatusNav(android.view.Window window, int statusbarColor, int navbarColor) {

    int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        window.getAttributes().flags |= flags;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int uiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiVisibility);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.getAttributes().flags &= ~flags;

        window.setStatusBarColor(statusbarColor);
        window.setNavigationBarColor(navbarColor);
    }
}
```

Use it in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#40FF0000");
        int navBarColor = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#6E00FF00");
        MyUtils.setWindowStatusNav(getWindow(), statusBarColor, navBarColor);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    }
}
```

To hide the navigation and status bars, call this method:

```
public static void setWindowStatusNavHidden(android.view.Window window) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int uiVisibility = window.getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiVisibility);
    }
}
```

Usage complete:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static boolean statusNavVisible = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#40FF0000");
        int navBarColor = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#6E00FF00");
        MyUtils.setWindowStatusNav(getWindow(), statusBarColor, navBarColor);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        Button btnShowHide = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        btnShowHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (statusNavVisible) {
                    statusNavVisible = false;
                    MyUtils.setWindowStatusNavHidden(getWindow());
                } else {
                    statusNavVisible = true;
                    MyUtils.setWindowStatusNav(getWindow(), statusBarColor, navBarColor);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make it Translucent, Add this in your theme.

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

If your also want it to Hide and to make your activity full screen.

```
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

and in your Activity onCreate Add.

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_activity_parent).windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
    } else {
        findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_activity_parent).systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, at least it works on API 31, thanks!